# what memory is reserved using resb

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, nasm

I wish to know which type of storage is reserved when using "resb" in NASM. I'm pretty sure it's RAM, but I want to be sure (maybe CPU cache?). All I could find in my research is that it is reserved in the .bss section, but that doesn't answer my question. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is reserved is space in the section you are in currently.  This is usually the `.bss` section (if you issued `section .bss` before issuing `resb`) but can be any other section you like.  It should be an *uninitialised data section* or you may get warnings.

One special section that is some times used with `resb` is the *absolute section.*  This is a pseudo section used to define symbols with absolute values, e.g. for defining structures using the `struc ... endstruc` mechanism.

All other sections are regions of addresses space.  Where they end up (and if they end up in the program's address space when its running at all) is up to the linker.  Usually, the `.bss` section is placed somewhere into the program's address space in a region likely backed by (or mapped to be backed by) actual RAM.  The specifics depend on the system you'll assemble this program for and run it on.

Note that CPU caches are largely transparent to the program.  You cannot “allocate data in the cache” and cache doesn't have address space associated with it.

Lastly, on hosted environments it often cannot be said whether data ends up in RAM at all.  This is because processes are subject to *memory mapping* where the processes' virtual address space is mapped to the systems physical address space in some manner.  This mapping is performed on demand and unless you actually access a region of address space, chances are that it is not mapped to anything at all.  And even after you access it, the CPU may cache the access for a while before flushing the data out to RAM.  And even if the data was in RAM at some point in time, the operating system may decide to *page out* (or *swap out*) your process onto disk if memory is tight.  All of this is of course transparent to your program and needs not to concern you.

You should not think about this too hard.  What is important is that this region of address space behaves like memory that is readable and writable.

Comment: You could add a bit about how "absolute" sections are used by NASM to support structure definitions. Same as for BSS sections, `resb` reserves space in that section. Unlike BSS, there is usually not one and only one mapping of a structure definition to program memory.

Comment: @ecm addressed.

Comment: @fuz Don't worry, I'm not thinking too hard about it. I just had to know for a school paper. Thx by the way